# How to add custom header while sending message to DLT using Spring Kafka non-blocking retries?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Kafka 2.8.0 with [non-blocking retries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic). I'm using single retry-topic with fixed backoff and dead-letter-topic. Here is my configuration:

```
@Bean
public RetryTopicConfiguration receiptRetryConfiguration(
        KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> kafkaTemplate,
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, byte[]> retryListenerContainerFactory
) {
    return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder.newInstance()
            .maxAttempts(3)
            .fixedBackOff(5000)
            .setTopicSuffixingStrategy(SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE)
            .useSingleTopicForFixedDelays()
            .doNotAutoCreateRetryTopics()
            .dltHandlerMethod(
                    new EndpointHandlerMethod(ConsumerErrorsHandler.class, "handleError")
            )
            .notRetryOn(List.of(SerializationException.class, EmptyMessageValueException.class))
            .listenerFactory(retryListenerContainerFactory)
            .create(kafkaTemplate);
}
```

I'm trying to implement [Failure Header Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-headers) and to add custom `error_code` header to messages sending to DLT:

```
@Bean(RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.DEAD_LETTER_PUBLISHING_RECOVERER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME)
public DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory factory(DestinationTopicResolver resolver) {
    DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory factory = new DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory(resolver);
    factory.setDeadLetterPublishingRecovererCustomizer(dlpr -> {
        dlpr.setHeadersFunction((record, exception) ->
                new RecordHeaders().add("error_code", getErrorCode(exception).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        );
    });
    return factory;
}
```

It works, but call of `dlpr.setHeadersFunction(...)` disables standart mechanism that adds retry headers: `retry_topic-attempts`, `retry_topic-backoff-timestamp`, `retry_topic-original-timestamp`.
As a result the messages sent to retry-topic consumed immediately without attempts limit.

Is there any way to add custom headers to messages sending to DLT in addition to `retry_topic-*` headers?

Is it possible to configure `DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory` only for messages sending to DLT-topics, not to retry-topics?

Answer (score 0):

Please open a new feature issue; I believe we need to add a `getHeadersFunction()` so you can build a composite function if one already exists (or we should add an `addHeaderFunction()` method).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues

Right now, you'd have to use reflection (e.g. `DirectFieldAccessor`) to get a reference to the existing function (`headersFunction` field).

Comment: Pull request issued: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/2161